# Vertically Align Text in a Table Cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I'm having difficulty in vertically aligning this pricing table's "Team" "Business" etc H4 headings in their respective table cells.

The table is a fairly simple one without too many styles applied so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have tried wrapping text in a div and setting the parent div's width and height to 100%. It didn't work.

This is the link for the practice website where I am working:
https://netterrain-new-features-clone.mystagingwebsite.com/network-documentation-pricing/

Comment: for h4 there will be margin by default. Please give margin:0 for h4

Comment: Why do you wrap the text in a div?

Comment: Why are you using `h4` inside a `th`, I'm wondering? Shows a distinct lack of understanding of how HTML and CSS works. Also, the use of multiple rows of `th` is also a bit... wrong, since the content within is definitely not a heading, but should be put in `td` instead. Oh well...

Comment: SO questions should be stand alone and not depend on external links to be complete (they can use external links to further explanation).

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** It's better to give code(not working) rather than webpages

Try adding following styles

```
table th, table td{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: ?? these are the default setting, why would you need to declare these again ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I checked by applying these styles. I think somewhere OP overriding these default ones.